# Expandable list view scrolling in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a table view as an expandable list view.I am using section as parent and cells as child.I am getting list view perfectly but the issue is that i want the expanded section view to come into view if the section at end of the screen is clicked. Currently it expands and stay there so one has to scroll it manually.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to call
`-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]`
But be careful. If you call that right after inserting rows for the section, the animation can look pretty bad (cells flying in from weird locations etc.) The easiest solution to that, is to do that after the row insertion animation is completed. Unfortunately, there is no callback for that and the easiest workaround is to use CATransaction callback like so:

```
// CATransaction is used to be able to have a callback after rows insertion is finished.

// This call opens CATransaction context
[CATransaction begin];

// This call begins tableView updates (not really needed if you only make one insertion call, or one deletion call, but in this example we do both)
[tableView beginUpdates];

// Insert and delete appropriate rows
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

// completionBlock will be called after rows insertion/deletion animation is done
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{
  // This call will scroll tableView to the top of the 'section' ('section' should have value of the folded/unfolded section's index)
  [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:section] // you can pass NSNotFound to scroll to the top of the section even if that section has 0 rows
                   atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                           animated:YES];
}];

// End table view updates
[tableView endUpdates];

// Close CATransaction context
[CATransaction commit];
```

If you do the folding/unfolding without animation, for example using plain `-[UITableView reloadData]`, you can safely call

`-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]`
directly after `-[UITableView reloadData]`

like so:

```
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:section] // 'section' is the index of the section you want to be scrolled to the top of the screen
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                         animated:YES];
```

Comment: where should i give this defenition

Comment: Well if you call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` after tapping section header, then add the `CATransaction` lines from my example in appropriate places and that should do the trick. If you do not use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` but just `reloadData`, then you can just call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` right after `reloadData`

Comment: i really din get the logic :(

Comment: Can u please explain me whats the code doing if it doesnt bother you ?

Comment: @VaisakhVinod I've edited the answer and added some comments. If anything is not clear, ask :)

Comment: Actually i am not doing any insertions or deletions here.just expanding and collapsing but This code works fine for me. lastly one doubt if i am selecting an section at top its scrolling above beyond view .how to adjust that. very sorry if i am irritating you?

Comment: @VaisakhVinod I don't mind ;) But I have no idea why it scrolls too far up…